# Exclude a specific folder with AWS CP Command

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

very very new to AWS & CLI so apologies.

I am using the following line which is working and excluding my wp-content directory but using the wildcards seems like a fudge. How should I specify the folder without the * ?

Sorry the * are around wp-content in the line below but are being removed it should read

"/(star)wp-content(Star)"

`aws s3 cp /var/www/html  s3://mybucket --recursive --exclude "/*wp-content*`

Thanks

Comment: No clear your question ?

Comment: edited, I'm trying to avoid using wildcards around the exclude"/wp-content"

Comment: How do I stop the site removing my * ?

Comment: @BobB format it as a code snippet instead of a quote. See this page: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thanks Mark, will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As S3 is an object store, the concept of directories is a virtual one. Instead the key is technically a string, so needs to be a text match.

if you want to make sure it is just excluding folders called wp-content, add more to the string, such as:

```
aws s3 cp /var/www/html  s3://mybucket --recursive --exclude "*/wp-content/*"
```

or if that folder is in the route of the /var/www/html folder, then:

```
aws s3 cp /var/www/html  s3://mybucket --recursive --exclude "wp-content/*"
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, much appreciated.